# Joins on Apache Hive 0.14 update and delete queries

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, antlr3, hiveql

I am searching for support of joins on update/delete Hive 0.14 which supports transactional queries, like teradata 15.00 supports the sql queries like

```
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE employee.deptno = department.deptno
AND department.location = 'NYC';

DELETE employee
FROM department AS d, employee
WHERE employee.dept_no = d.dept_no
AND salary_pool < 50000;

UPDATE e
FROM employee AS e, department AS d
SET salary = salary * 1.05
WHERE e.emp_no = d.emp_no;
```

Here as I reference a second table in hive, I get

```
delete from album where album.id = cart.albumid;
```

Getting Error :

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:35 Invalid table alias or column reference 'cart': (possible column names are: id, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the `cart` table through one kind of `join`

```
DELETE album 
FROM album INNER JOIN cart ON (album.id = cart.albumid)
```

In the examples you provided, the tables are joined through `,`